# Swashbuckle for Azure Function: customize header

Tags: azure-functions, swagger-ui

In my Azure Functions I added Swashbuckle and it is working.

```
[SwaggerIgnore]
[FunctionName("swaggerUi")]
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> SwaggerUi(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = SwaggerRoutes.UiRoute)] 
    HttpRequestMessage req,
    [SwashBuckleClient] ISwashBuckleClient swashBuckleClient)
{
    return Task.FromResult(swashBuckleClient.CreateSwaggerUIResponse(req, 
                           req.CreateSwaggerDocumentRoute()));
}
```

Now, I wanted to customize the header with some information about my apis.

[image]

I found a [post](https://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/azure/adding-swagger-ui-documentation-to-azure-function-apis/) where that guy said it is enough to add some configuration in the `host.json` like:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    ...

    "Swashbuckle": {
      "Documents": [
        {
          "Title": "YOUR_TITLE",
          "Version": "v1",
          "Description": "YOUR_DESCRIPTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but for me it doesn't work. What is it necessary to do?

Answer (score -1):

Ok so this is now i managed to get it working. When you create a fresh Azure Function in Visual Studio, by default it created a V3 Azure Function which runs on `.netcore3.0`.

I did not notice that in the first place and installed this nuget `AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle;`

Added two functions, one to give `Swagger JSON` and another one for the `Swagger UI`

When i ran the app, it gave some errors which were unrelated. After a quick search i ended up on this [Github Issue #21](https://github.com/yuka1984/azure-functions-extensions-swashbuckle/issues/21)

1. After this, i quickly checked the `Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions` version it was pointing to the latest `V3.x` i downgraded it to `V1.0.36`
2. I edited my `func.csproj` and pointed the Target Framework to `.netcore2.1` with Azure func v2

   `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>`
   `<AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>`
3. I noticed the article that you posted the `route` was mentioned as `/` if you use this then you will get a `RoutePatternException`
4. I changed the route to something meaningfull and it worked awesome.

When you run it, the console shows

[image]

Here i browse to see if the `SwaggerUI` works

[image]

I did also test the `SwaggerJSON`

[image]

Comment: thank you! Is that mean I can't use the latest version of `.net core` 3.1 or `Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions`?

Comment: Yes both. This library only works for .`netcore2` for now! Please upvote and accept the answer if it worked for you